# field type of file in joomla 3 custom component

Tags: joomla, upload, field, components

I am developing a custom component in Joomla 3. In administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/forms/page.xml I am using a field type of 'file' for uploading audio, video and image files. As we all know for this type of field to do the job properly we have to do a few modifications. I have searched in stackoverflow and google and found some solutions. What I need is a step-by-step guide which I think will be of great help to many developers. I don't want to use 3rd party extensions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the field type="media" which shows you one way of extending the file field to support the actual upload.  So, use the field type="file" if you want to use your own javascript etc and in various ways customize. Use the field type="media" if you want to use the core js. Media will default to the images folder as a location but you can change the field attributes to point it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Where is media.php located in joomla 3.2.1? It is not in /libraries/joomla/form/fields/